# Create Unqiue case-insensitive constraint on two varchar fields

Tags: sql, oracle10g, unique-constraint

In Oracle 10g, how do I add a unique case-insensitive constraint on two varchar fields?  For example, given the following records already in the table:

```
"Stephen", "Swensen"
"John", "Smith"
```

The following inserts would be invalid:

```
"stephen", "Swensen"
"John", "smith"
"stephen", "swensen"
```

But the following inserts would be valid:

```
"Stephen", "Smith"
"John", "Swensen"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your table is called **person**, and the first and last name columns are called **first_name** and **last_name**, add this unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE person ADD CONSTRAINT person_name_unique
    UNIQUE(LOWER(first_name),LOWER(last_name));
```

Let me know if I understood your question correctly and made the correct assumptions about your table layout.

Comment: I don't think `LOWER` belongs in a constraint like that. It's better to specify a collation.

Comment: You got it, thanks! I also found this, which works as well: create unique index UK_U_FIRSTNAME_LASTNAME on PERSON (LOWER(FIRST_NAME), LOWER(LAST_NAME));

Comment: LOWER(COL_NAME) is not working inside UNIQUE. Gives error SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Answer (score 12):

I've managed to get it working by doing:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX person_name_upper ON person(
    UPPER(first_name), UPPER(last_name));
```

Comment: using postgresql 9.4, this is the solution that worked for me.michael's accepted solution above threw a syntax exception, not liking the `lower` keyword inside the `unique` declaration.